# AccessViolationException when calling C-DLL functions in C#

Tags: c#, exception, dll

I´m trying to call a function from a C DLL with C#. When I do that I´m getting a AccessViolationException (..attempted to read or write protected memory). 
I don´t have the original C-Code, only the DLL.
I´m rather sure that my marshalling of the struct is correct.

This program should communicate with a multi channel analyzer over a USB connection. There are many functions in the library. Most of them work fine.

The original declaration of the FUNCTION looks something like this:

```
int32_t CN_API AddBoard(int32_t handle, ParamStruct Params, int32_t *bId);
```

The original declaration of the STRUCT looks something like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    ConnectionType LinkType;
    int32_t LinkNum;
    int32_t Node;
    uint32_t BaseAddress;
    char Address[ADDR_LEN + 1];
} ParamStruct;
```

ConnectionType is an ENUM an looks like this:

```
typedef enum 
{
    conn_USB             = 0L,
    conn_OpticalLink     = 1L,
    conn_ETH             = 2L,
    conn_Serial          = 3L,
} ConnectionType;
```

and for the array:

```
#define ADDR_LEN   (255)
```

I´ve translated everything to C# code:

```
public class Digitizer
{
    [DllImport("CNLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern unsafe int AddBoard(int handle, ParamStruct Params, ref int bId);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 276)]
    public struct ParamStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
        public ConnectionType LinkType;
        public int LinkNum;
        public int Node;
        public uint BaseAddress;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string Address;
    }

    public enum ConnectionType : long
    {
        conn_USB = 0L,
        conn_OpticalLink = 1L,
        conn_ETH = 2L,
        conn_Serial = 3L,
    }
}
```

Here´s my "main code":

```
int ret;
int handle = 0;
int boardId = 0;

Digitizer.ParamStruct Params = new Digitizer.ParamStruct();

Params.LinkType = Digitizer.ConnectionType.conn_USB;
Params.LinkNum = 1;
Params.Node = 0;
Params.BaseAddress = 0;
Params.Address = "";

ret = Digitizer.AddBoard(handle, connParams, ref boardId);
```

Does anyone have an idea what and where the problem could be? Maybe the Garbage Collector does clear something? When I look into the disassembly I see that it crashes at a "call" command. If you need more detailed code, tell me.

I hope anybody of you can help me. I´m sitting on this problem since days ;).

Comment: is the char an ANSI or Unicode char? ie, does the C expect 256 bytes and you're sending 256 words. You might be better off with a byte array instead of a string in the equivalent C# class.

Comment: Your ConnectionType declaration is wrong, delete " : long".  If you still have trouble then be sure to contact the owner of this DLL for support.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: it´s an ANSI char. But I will try an byte array ;).

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks for you answer. I thought that a C# enum declaration is automatically int32? That´s the reason why I declared it with ": long", because in the C enum the parameters declared with suffix "L". Correct me, if I am wrong... But I will try that.

Comment: *long* in C is a 32-bit type on Windows, *long* in C# is a 64-bit type.  The extra L in the enum declaration is nonsensical but harmless.

Comment: First try changing the MarshalAs type from ByValTStr to UnmanagedType.LPStr. The T means 'ansi or unicode depending' and its probably choosing unicode as your C# app will be unicode.

Comment: @Hans Passant: That´s right. Bad failure XD. I changed sizes of marshalling and in StructureLayout and corrected the enum. Now it works! :) Thank you very much!